# Give a space between menu and dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out on how to give a space in between my top navigation menu and the dropdown list (when hovered). Here is the screenshot of it.
[there is no space so it looks kind of crowded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bott1.png)

I've tried adding a margin-top: 10px; to the css of the dropdown, but it made the hover not working anymore.

Here is my code:

```css
.header {
                position: relative;
                top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 140px;
                line-height: 140px;
                background-color: #060930;
            }

            .header .btn {
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: middle;
                line-height: normal;
                margin-left: 2%;
            }

            .ad, .arch, .abt {
                font-family: 'product_sansbold';
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
                background-color: transparent;
                border: transparent;
                cursor: pointer;
                margin: 0 4px;
            }

            .ad {
                color: #FBF3FF;
                font-size: 32px;
            }

            .arch, .abt {
                color: #a1a6e6;
                font-size: 18px;
            }

            .arch:hover, .abt:hover {
                transition-duration: 0.3s;
                color: #d7daff;
            }
            .arch:active, .abt:active {
                color: #d7daff;
            }

            .dropdown {
                position: relative;
                display: inline-block;
            }

            .dropdown-cont {
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
                background-color: #a1a6e6;
                min-width: 160px;
                border-radius: 6px;
                z-index: 1;
            }

            .dropdown-cont a {
                font-family: 'product_sansbold';
                color: #060930;
                padding: 14px 16px;
                text-decoration: none;
                display: block;
            }

            .dropdown:hover .dropdown-cont {
                display: block;
                background-color: #a1a6e6;
            }

            .dropdown-cont a:hover {
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<div class="header">
            <div class="btn">
                <button class="ad" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='index.html'"><b>AD.</b></button>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="arch" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='archive.html'"><b>Archive</b></button>
                    <div class="dropdown-cont">
                        <a href="stories.html">Stories</a>
                        <a href="photos.html">Photos</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="abt" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='about.html'"><b>About</b></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome on the Stack Overflow. Try adding `.dropdown-cont { padding-top: 20px; }` or another value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is give it a border rather than a margin. Margin will shift that entire element down so once you stop hovering, it wont appear. I have given it a border of 10px but you can tweak it  however you like.

```css
.header {
                position: relative;
                top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 140px;
                line-height: 140px;
                background-color: #060930;
            }

            .header .btn {
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: middle;
                line-height: normal;
                margin-left: 2%;
            }

            .ad, .arch, .abt {
                font-family: 'product_sansbold';
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
                background-color: transparent;
                border: transparent;
                cursor: pointer;
                margin: 0 4px;
            }

            .ad {
                color: #FBF3FF;
                font-size: 32px;
            }

            .arch, .abt {
                color: #a1a6e6;
                font-size: 18px;
            }

            .arch:hover, .abt:hover {
                transition-duration: 0.3s;
                color: #d7daff;
            }
            .arch:active, .abt:active {
                color: #d7daff;
            }

            .dropdown {
                position: relative;
                display: inline-block;
            }

            .dropdown-cont {
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
                background-color: #a1a6e6;
                min-width: 160px;
                border-radius: 6px;
                z-index: 1;
                border-top: 10px solid #060930;
            }

            .dropdown-cont a {
                font-family: 'product_sansbold';
                color: #060930;
                padding: 14px 16px;
                text-decoration: none;
                display: block;
            }

            .dropdown:hover .dropdown-cont {
                display: block;
                background-color: #a1a6e6;
            }

            .dropdown-cont a:hover {
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<div class="header">
            <div class="btn">
                <button class="ad" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='index.html'"><b>AD.</b></button>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="arch" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='archive.html'"><b>Archive</b></button>
                    <div class="dropdown-cont">
                        <a href="stories.html">Stories</a>
                        <a href="photos.html">Photos</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="abt" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='about.html'"><b>About</b></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
</html>
```